# Make a picture gallery floating in a row in center

Tags: html, css, gallery

I've been trying to make a simple gallery where pictures float in a row but in center.. Sorry for my bad english.

But I followed w3s example and tried with my logo, but it floats from left to right, I want it to be as centered as possible but with more than 1 picture in a row.

Here is my css

```
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d60079;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
  }

div.img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #f0068a;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float:center;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="testlogo.png">
    <img src="test4.png" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="testlogo.png">
    <img src="test4.png" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `float: center`. Simply add `text-align: center` css to the parent div and everything will be centered.

**Edit**

If you're looking to center the row of images, I'd suggest using flex box (see the inline styling)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d60079;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center
    position: inline-block;
  }

div.img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #f0068a;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="testlogo.png">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="testlogo.png">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the picture are still floating on the left side.

Comment: what do you mean picture? Did you mean the parent div? that contains both the pictures and the description?

Comment: I have 2 pictures, for example, if you're working in word, you can choose to write from the left side, center or right side, currently, my pictures are going from left, I want them to go from center

Comment: Thanks alot :D you have no idea how happy I am at the moment :D

Comment: Personally, I avoid using `floats` because they tend to give unexpected results. You can do the same thing using either tables, or just `text-aligns` a lot of the time.

Comment: I wanted to use tables but when i tried, the picture became the background, I haven't slept for 2 days so I was unfocused and didn't check the code at first... but you have to see the site later, and again, thanks alot